# iOS Google Maps Issue

Tags: ios, google-maps

I developing a Google Maps application for iOS. I have a problem. I sent request to the Google Maps then returns an empty. This issue has become the last two days. Please help me

**Request:**
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=4.963404,52.337971&sensor=true

**Result:**

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to write

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.337971,4.963404&sensor=true
```

4.963404, 52.337971 is in the middle of the indian ocean. The nearest valid address is thousands of kilometers away.